# List comprehension for two related lists with output sorted by second list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to solve the problem how to transfer these two for loops into one list comprehension. We have these two lists and I would like to sort the first list according to the second list. With for loops it looks like this:

```
numbers = [-2, -8, 1, 17]
nov = [1, 2, 8, 17]
pon = []
  for i in nov:
     for x in numbers:
         if abs(x) == i:
             pon.append(x)
print(pon)
->>>[1, -2, -8, 17]
```

Is it somehow possible write these two loops as list comprehension?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same output in a list comprehension by sequencing your for loops and your if condition in the same order as your nested logic. For example (renamed a couple variables to make the relationships stand out a bit more):

```
absolutes = [1, 2, 8, 17]
numbers = [-2, -8, 1, 17]

result = [n for a in absolutes for n in numbers if abs(n) == a]
print(result)
# [1, -2, -8, 17]
```